# Matrix multiplication and substitution

Tags: matrices, vectors

I have

$$
\mathbf{b} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\mathbf{a} +
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
+
t
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\mathbf{b}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right)
$$

My book says that this should hold for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $t=0$ then

$$
\mathbf{b} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\mathbf{a} +
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

But now my book says that if I insert my second equation in my first equation, then I get

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\mathbf{b}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

but I don't see why. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

You get, at first,

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}a +\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}a +\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} + t\left(\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}b +\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\right)$$

Now you can cross out some of the vectors since they appear on both sides, and you get

$$t\left(\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}b +\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\right) = 0$$

Now, divide the equation by $t$.

Comment: But that equation only holds for $t = 0$, so am I allowed to divide by $t$?

Comment: @Jamgreen Which equation only holds for $t=0$?

Comment: @Jamgreen Are $a$ and $b$ functions of $t$?

Comment: No. $a$ and $b$ are constants.. But my second equation $\mathbf{b} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\mathbf{a} +
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$ only holds for $t=0$

Comment: @Jamgreen This equation does not contain $t$, therefore you cannot say "it only holds for $t=0$". The equation is either true or not, given the variables that appear **inside** the equation. For example, $x^2=1$ only holds if $x=1$ or $x=-1$, but you cannot say $x^2 =1$ only holds if $t=1$.

Comment: @Jamgreen The equation you get when you insert $t=0$ is a thing that you know is true. The fact that you know that it's true because you found that out by setting $t=0$ does not mean that that equation "depends" on $t$.

Comment: Ah ofc. Thank you! But I still don't understand why I can divide by $t$ when the equation should hold for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Jamgreen Well, if it holds for all $t$, it also holds for some nonzero $t$. Alternatively, you can say that it holds for $t=1$.